# Desktop icon registry entries

Tags: windows, windows-xp

l need some help, l am currently setting up logoff scripts which if a user deletes IE8 it restors it,

at the moment l have the registry entries for IE8 which was ie_icon.reg,

what l need help is what the entries are for

My documents, my computer and the recycle bin.

would anyone know what they are.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know off the top of my head, but I can give you a suggestion to find it:

Get a 'diff' utility (winmerge for example). Save your registry, then change the icon settings using the TweakUI PowerToy. Save your registry again in a different file, and generate a 'diff' between the two registry files. This should point you to the registry keys of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better results using the GPO setting: User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop. You have access to all the icons you're asking about.

I usually do this to hide icons, but you should be able to "disable" hiding icons to make sure they show up.